# Lambda expression for List<string> property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have a model that have list properties.

```
public class Class01 
{
  List<string> PropA {get; set;}
  List<string> PropB {get; set;}
}
```

now in my view, i want to create @Html.TextBoxFor  for each of the item in each of the list. i am not good with lamba expressions and so cant figureout how to provide a valid lambda expression for the above requirement.

**Note : i dont want to prefer the following way :**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropA[0])
```

I want to loop through all properties and then nested loop through each items for creating textboxes.

please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You need a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@foreach` :

```
 @foreach (Propa p in model.PropA ) {
}
```

Comment: Hi.... Thanks for reply.. :) 
Actually i would like to prefer a bit different solution.
there are almost 50 list properties. i dont want to hard code all those loops. i would rather like to loop through all properties, and into that loop, some lambda expressions that could create textboxes for all string items in all lists.